# Does procuring cause in real estate apply when you have to change an agent

Tags: california, real-estate

I found a property for sale online and I toured it with an agent a week ago. There was no signed agreement between the agent and me. However, the agent is not willing to write an offer for me as they insist that the asking price is great and that I pay a higher price than I wanted(about 7% higher). I had an argument with them and I had to fire the agent. I'm looking for a new agent who is willing to write an offer for me. However, one new agent told me that they can't write an offer for me because of procuring cause. If this applies, it would seem that I am stuck: the agent who showed me the property is not willing to write an offer for me; other agents cannot write me an offer because of procuring cause.

BTW, the property is in California.